# In which Star Wars book did Mara Jade and Lando Calrissian go on the mission to find Jorj Car'das as referenced in the "Hand of Thrawn" duology?

Tags: star-wars, books, star-wars-legends

There are so many references to the occasion in the duology that it makes me think it had to have been written about. It's mentioned to have taken place six years before the events of Timothy Zahn's "Vision of the Future" (which is ANH +19), which should put it at around the time of the Black Fleet Crisis (<strike>ANH</strike> ROTJ +12 / ANH +16-17), The New Rebellion (<strike>ANH</strike> ROTJ +13 / ANH +17), or the Corellian Trilogy (<strike>ANH</strike> ROTJ +14 / ANH +18).

EDIT: Ahh, the back of *Vision of the Future* lists the novel chronology as "*×* years from ROTJ" for all novels except itself, which is "*×* years after ANH". Silly inconsistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually happens concurrently with Barbara Hambly's *Children of the Jedi* novel, during which Mara appears with Lando on the other side of a holocom call.

> “What? Who is it?”
>
> Leia prodded her husband’s shoulder. “I told you you should have waited for her to call back.” She turned back to the holo image of the woman in the field, fiery hair tousled, green eyes blinking into the dim glow of the lights on her end of the transmission. She wore a gold chain around her neck and a shirt Leia recognized as belonging to Lando Calrissian. “Mara, I’m sorry …”
>
> “No, it’s all right.” Mara Jade rubbed her eyes with a quick gesture, and that seemed to take care of any residual sleepiness, as if she’d clicked off a switch. “I must look like one of the Nightsisters of Dathomir. What time is it where you are? What’s up? Is there a problem?”
>
> [...]
>
> Mara made an extremely unladylike comment and Lando Calrissian appeared behind her shoulder, waxed and combed and dressed in his best purple satin for an evening out.
>
> **-- Barbara Hambly: *Children of the Jedi, Chapter 12***

No mention is made of the fact that they are undercover, which, as you said, is in fact something Timothy Zahn put into his *Vision of the Future*. I doubt that Barbara Hambly had intended it as an undercover sting when she wrote it, more likely she did it so she could have Luke freed up to pair him with her original character of Callista (but that is just my assumption).

Comment: Ahh, that explains it - I knew the situation of Mara and Lando being together in some form wasn't entirely unfamiliar, but I wasn't all that enamored with _Children of the Jedi_ and so never bothered to read it more than once. And it looks like the reason I got the timeline wrong is because the back of _Vision of the Future_ lists all the other novels as being "× years after _Return of the Jedi_" except for the "Hand of Thrawn" duology, which is listed as "19 years after _Star Wars: A New Hope_". Silly oversight.

Comment: @Sandwich Same with me, haven't read it in ages either. You're right, it's not all that great...